# how to log on host if dc on virtual server

Tags: windows-server-2008, login, hyper-v

If my only Domain Controller is on a Windows 2008 Hyper-v server then do I always have to use a local (non-domain) credentials to login to the host server & the Hyper-v server after a reboot?

I just want to be sure ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use cached credentials until the guest-os domain-controller comes online... or simply set the instance with the guest-os domain-controller to automatically start on boot ... and wait until it comes online before attempting to log into the host server.